# user32!gSharedInfo on Windows 8/10?

Tags: c++, user32

In Windows 7 x64 I can get SharedInfo with

```
SHAREDINFO *SharedInfo = (SHAREDINFO *)GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("user32"), "gSharedInfo");
```

In Windows 8/10 it returns an address but cannot access the members, gives access violation.

I'm trying to get the cHandleEntries from SharedInfo->pServerInfo->cHandleEntries but cannot on Windows 8/10, anyone have some pointers? Is this some added security? Any way around it?

Comment: Are you sure the layout is not changed of this struct?

Comment: No I'm not, think I tried windbg a long time ago but maybe need to try again. Haven't found any doc on the net, stops at Windows 7.

Comment: Using pdbxtract (don't have access to a win8/10 pc atm to attach windbg), i was unable to find the tagSHAREDINFO struct in windows 10 symbols.

Comment: If I view the raw memory at SharedInfo in VS memory viewer it's all ?? so I don't think it matters if the struct changed, not yet I mean.

Comment: Thanks Mark, we were typing at the same time :) My best guess is MS decided this was too much of a security hole.

Comment: I might have access to a win10 pc in a few hours, I'll take a peek at user32.dll there to see if it is still used, and if so, how

Comment: Just read an article about Windows 10, another reason might that there are hooks MS doesn't want you to know about or disable, apparently all keystrokes are sent to MS servers etc. Twilight zone music begins...

Answer (score 0):

Found out with my shiny new kernel debugging experiments that it was just a bug on my part, storing a 64 bit pointer in 32 bit variable type of thing. Windows 7 had me covered tho somehow!

Comment: Probably because Windows 7's 64-bit user32.dll is (for no reason I can see) based below the 4GB mark...